# How to get empty and not empty collections at the same time in Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

I study Hibernate and have confronted with such problem:

I have two entities

**Person class:**

```
@Entity
public class Person {

  ...

  @OneToMany(...)
  @Where(clause = "is_completed = false")
  private List<Task> tasks;

  ...

}
```

**Task class:**

```
@Entity
public class Task {

  ...

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(...)
  private Person person;

  ...
}
```

I need to get persons with NOT completed tasks (I use `@Where` for this) but also I need to get persons with no tasks at all at the same time.
I've used

`SELECT DISTINCT person FROM Person person LEFT JOIN person.tasks`

but I get only persons with not completed tasks and that's all. What should be the query to get also persons with an empty list of tasks? Thanks for any help.

Comment: not sure if it works, but can you add a second clause in `@Where` which checks if a person has no task assign? or would it be okay for you to use `Criteria` API?

Comment: add a where person.task.(id) IS NULL or person.task.isCompleted = false